# Pre-trained model is unable to detect new license plates properly

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn

I have downloaded a license plate recognition project from GitHub. It is able to recognize images in the project repository. However, it does a poor job at detecting new images. Do I need to retrain the model?